# Angular & svg - Can't find any SVG tags for angular

Tags: angular

Has anyone tried using an svg with angular? I have successfully used them with angularJS, but I can't seem to find any way to use them in Angular.

In AngularJS I am able to do this:

```
<svg ng-x={{svg.x}} ng-y={{svg.y}} ng-attr-view_box="{{svg.viewBox}}">
<path ng-attr-d="{{svg.path}}"/>
</svg>
```

But none of those tags seem to work on angular. any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

In Angular [attribute binding](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/attribute-class-style-bindings-angular) is like [attr.disabled] = "", [attr.attribute-name]=""

Answer (score 1):

ok I figured it out: `[attr.viewBox]="svg.viewBox"`